# How to check default http transport mechanism in WSO2 ESB 4.9.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I want to tune transport level settings in WSO2 ESB 4.9.0 but I am not sure of default transport, wither nhttp and pass through transport. I read in some documents that pass through transport is advanced than nhttp transport.

Is there any configuration file I need to change the setting or default is pass through http transport